# Which is faster, uploading a file to HDFS or creating and writing to an HDFS file directly?

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, bigdata

Basically I have a program, which uploads files to the HDFS. The files are uploaded at the end of a task's execution. So, what happens is that a lot of tasks are at the same time (at the end of their execution) uploading files to the HDFS, thus creating contention. The file sizes are less than an HDFS block (< 64 MB). I was wondering, if it would be faster to just create an HDFS file in advance (while task is doing some processing to avoid contention), and then when processing is finished, read the content of a local file in a string,  and just append that string to the HDFS file which was already created in advance.

So, basically my question is, which has more overhead, creating an HDFS file or appending a string to an already created HDFS file?

Comment: I would just try it and see. I don't think it would be that hard

Comment: True, but I just wanted some opinions.

Comment: Please provide more information. What do you mean: ' if it would be faster to just read the content of such a file in a string, create an HDFS file and then write that string to the HDFS file directly'. How it different from 'I have a program, which uploads files to the HDFS'

Comment: Basically if you read my whole post, I say that I will create the files while doing processing, so at the end, I just need to append a string to the already created files. So it all boils down to which has more overhead, creating an HDFS file or appending to an HDFS file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested this myself, and have noted that creating an HDFS file takes almost the same time as appending to it. This is assuming that the content written is less than the HDFS block size. If you upload an HDFS file, that would be equivalent to creating the HDFS file and appending to it, so it means that it takes twice as much time as just appending to it.